# Returning custom "Role" attribute as application claims

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am  working with Azure AD B2C and I want to return a custom attribute called "Role" as claim to the application after user login. The user should not be able to edit the Role attribute data. Below is what I have done so far:

1. Created custom attribute called "Role", with the goal that admin users can update that property but not normal users themselves.
2. I use custom policies for Signup/Signin and it works fin without the Role attribute.

Now, I have done below changes in the custom policies to return Role attribute as claim:
**B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions**

a. Added claimtype in the building blocks section as below:

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_Role">
            <DisplayName>Role</DisplayName>
            <DataType>string</DataType>
            <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
    </ClaimType>
```

b. Added output claim for the attribute in AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress and AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId technical profile in B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions policy

```
<!-- Read data after user resets the password. -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
          <OutputClaims>  
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Role" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!-- Read data after user authenticates with a local account. -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
          <OutputClaims>  
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Role" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

**B2C_1A_signup_signin**
c. Finally, in my B2C_1A_signup_signin policy added outputclaim as below:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Role" PartnerClaimType="extension_Role" DefaultValue="" />
```

Now, when I test the policy using JWT.ms , I get below error and logs are not providing any insights:

> AADB2C90037: An error occurred while processing the request. Please
> contact administrator of the site you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

There is a *b2c-extensions-app* created by default in Azure AD B2C tenant and the details of that app needs to be configured under the Azure AD Read technical profiles in B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions file as below:

```
<Metadata>
          <!--Insert b2c-extensions-app application ID here>  
           <Item Key="ClientId">{application id here}</Item>
          <!--Insert b2c-extensions-app application ObjectId here-->
          <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">{clientid here}</Item>
         </Metadata>
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy